# How do I prove this triangle is equilateral and not isosceles?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose you have a given equilateral triangle $ABC$ and a semicircle is constructed on the side $BC$ with $BC$ as diameter, suppose also that points $K$ and $L$ divides the semicircle into three equal arcs, how do I prove that triangle $OLC$ is equilateral? Where $O$ is the centre of the circle.

Comment: Try showing $K$ and $L$ are on the midpoints of the sides of the equilateral

Comment: Specifically, try to show that $K\in AB$ and $L\in AC$ up to switching names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this diagram shed some light?

[image]

Comment: You're always there to arrive with very informative graphics, nice +1